# DomDocument->load() not loading .plist

Tags: php, plist, domdocument

I use CFPropertylist to load a plist into a DomDocument. Now my .plist is fairly big with 3MB and now the following fails:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if(!$doc->load($file)) throw new DOMException();
```

it always throws an exception, but the message is empty. How can I find out what is wrong?

```
plutil MyFile.plist // shows MyFile.plist: OK
```

I don't have any clue where to start searching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it throws a warning when your XML is invalid. Check this post: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php#69295

Comment: that was it ;-). Warning: Illegal character at.... bla bla.... I'll have to use it as in the comments, then it works